# Can Gitlab API upload file to repo?

Tags: gitlab

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#upload-a-file

After upload image, I got the url, but didn't added to my repo files?

Can we upload image to repo files?

Answer (score 4):

The [`/projects/:id/uploads`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#upload-a-file) doesn't add anything to your project's repository. The description says:

> Uploads a file to the specified project to be used in an **issue** or **merge request description**, or a **comment**.

To upload a file to the actual repo you need to use the [`/projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#create-new-file-in-repository) endpoint.

To upload an **image** specifically, you'll need to:

- Set the `encoding` parameter to `base64`
- Convert your image to base64
- Remove the `data:image/png;base64,` part at the beginning
- Set the `content` parameter to the  remaining part of the base64

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand this
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository

For file, as you said you can checkout below code.

```
    #read the yaml file which has the data to be uploaded
    from base64 import b64encode
    with open('myfile.yml', 'rb') as f:
        bin_content = f.read()
    #encode
    b64_content = b64encode(bin_content).decode('utf-8')    
    
    #create payload
    payload = {"branch": "main", "author_email": "author email", "encoding":"base64", "author_name": "author name",
       "content": b64_content, "commit_message": "commit msg"}
    res = common.api_request("PUT", URL, headers, payload, files)
    print (res)
```