# How to upload image for current gitlab issue

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, gitlab-api

I am creating vue3 app where I am using gitlab api. I would like to have an option to upload some files (img or pdf) for current issue.

this is my input file in template

```
<input @change="onFileChange" type="file" />
```

and methods

```
onFileChange(e) {
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (files.length > 0){
        console.log(files)
      this.image = files
      } 
    },
    
    createNewIssue(arg) {
      console.log(this.image)
      if(this.image) {
        const url = `https://gitbo.ddns.net/api/v4/projects/${arg}/uploads`;
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: SERVICES.gitlab.gitlabHeaders,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            file: '@' + this.image
          }),
        }).then((response) => {
          response.json()
          const url = `https://gitbo.ddns.net/api/v4/projects/${arg}/issues`;
          fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: SERVICES.gitlab.gitlabHeaders,
            body: JSON.stringify({
              title: this.newIssueTitle,
              description: this.newIssueDescription + response.markdown,
              assignee_id: 52,
            }),
          }).then((response) => response.json());
        });
      }
       else {
        const url = `https://gitbo.ddns.net/api/v4/projects/${arg}/issues`;
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: SERVICES.gitlab.gitlabHeaders,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            title: this.newIssueTitle,
            description: this.newIssueDescription,
            assignee_id: 52,
          }),
        }).then((response) => response.json());
      }
```

when I console.log(files) I see something was uploaded[image]

it means something was assign to this.image. In function createNewIssue I am getting argument which is project id in gitlab. I have something in this.image  so it takes first condition and it create issue, unfortunatelly when I look in my Network tab I see {file: "@[object FileList]"} and In final result it cause that this image is undefined [image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: GitLab clearly asks for a single file but you are assigning an array of files

Comment: @dontHaveName I changed my files to file and I get error " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')" Where I should change it?

Comment: I'd change ```file: '@' + this.image``` into ```file: '@' + this.image[0]```, but there might be more issues in the code, haven't tested it

Comment: @dontHaveName it makes sense but it doesn't work I have then cors policy issue  even if another gitlab request don't have problems with cors and when I fixed cors with middleware on heroku I get response 500 internal server error

Comment: @dontHaveName  EDIT  I get response 400 error: "file is invalid"

Comment: have you actually read the documentation? You probably should. E.g. I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361810/can-gitlab-api-upload-file-to-repo

Comment: @dontHaveName  yes I read it and I saw also that post but didn't help me. Could you please answer this question with your code example if you know the answer?