# GitLab "Upload a File" API returns "file is invalid" after POST

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, base64, gitlab-api

I'm trying to upload an image from a WordPress backend to a GitLab project, such that I can use that image in an issue. The image comes from a ContactForm7 form and I store it in WordPress first.

[GitLab has a specific API for uploading files use in issues](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#upload-a-file), but no matter what I sent, it returns `{"error":"file is invalid"}`. [Another Stackoverlow issue to a similar question exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361810/can-gitlab-api-upload-file-to-repo), but the solution is incomplete and/or does not work. **I don't want to commit an image**, I'm fine with it being in this weird upload architecture of GitLab.

I tried using just the filename in the body, the internal path, the public URL to the image and a base64 encoded version. All tries lead to the same invalid file error. I can't find any documentation on how GitLab expects my image and what I need to do for GitLab to accept it. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```php
function uploadToGitLab($contact_form) {
    $contact_form_id = $contact_form->id();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $files = $submission->uploaded_files();
    
    $markdownImage = "";
    if (!empty($files) && $contact_form_id == "721") {
        // move image from temp folder to upload folder
        $image_file = file_get_contents($files['anhang'][0]);
        $image_name = basename($files['anhang'][0]);
        $imageUpload = wp_upload_bits(basename($files['anhang'][0]), null, $image_file);    
        $image_filename = $imageUpload['url'];

        // Convert Image to Base64
        $image_type = pathinfo($imageUpload['file']);
        $image_stringdata = file_get_contents($imageUpload['file']);
        $image_base64 = base64_encode($image_stringdata);
        
        $uploadImageHeader = array(
            'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
            // Set encoding to base64 if trying to send base64 image:
            'encoding' => 'base64'
        );
        $uploadImageBody = array(
            // Using the raw file uploaded in the form:
            //'file' => '@'. $files["anhang"][0]
            // Using just the filename:
            //'file' => '@'. basename($files["anhang"][0])
            // Using the image public URL:
            //'file' => '@'. $image_filename
            // Using base64 encoding of the image:
            'file' => '@' . $image_base64
        );
        $uploadArgs = array(
            'header' => $uploadImageHeader,
            'body' => $uploadImageBody
        );
        $imageResponse = wp_remote_post("https://example.com/api/v4/projects/MYPROJECTID/uploads?private_token=TOKEN", $uploadArgs);
        $markdownImage = $imageResponse["markdown"];
    }
```

As described above, no matter what I put into the `'file' => '@' .` line, it seems to be `invalid`.

I tried:

- @image.png
- @/wordpress/uploads/path/to/image.png
- @https://example.com/image.png
- @base64encodedimage

But all return `invalid`. What is GitLab expecting?

Comment: `'file' => '@' . $image_base64` makes no sense; with the `@`, it expects a local file path it can read from. Can you show a vaer_dump of $files, please, so that we can see what you are actually dealing with?

Comment: @CBroe I used `@` because of the GitLab docu. `$files['anhang']` is a path to the image on the webserver uploaded using the form. So `/pathdetails/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/1240814955/test.png`. The question is what path or file do I need to give the API, such that it can take it?

Comment: The `@filepath` is cURL syntax - I don't think `wp_remote_post` actually supports that. You will either need to assemble the correct multipart request body yourself, if you want to keep using that method - or switch to something else (like the actual PHP cURL implementation.)